Flutter webrtc audio call are not working
I did the same things as Flutter demo.
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_webrtc/flutter_webrtc.dart';
import '../services/signalling.service.dart';

class CallScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String callerId, calleeId;
  final dynamic offer;

  const CallScreen({
    super.key,
    this.offer,
    required this.callerId,
    required this.calleeId,
  });

  @override
  State<CallScreen> createState() => _CallScreenState();
}

class _CallScreenState extends State<CallScreen> {
  final socket = SignallingService.instance.socket;

  final _localRTCVideoRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();
  final _remoteRTCVideoRenderer = RTCVideoRenderer();

  MediaStream? _localStream;
  RTCPeerConnection? _rtcPeerConnection;
  List<RTCIceCandidate> rtcIceCandidates = [];

  bool isAudioOn = true;
  bool isCallActive = false;
  DateTime? callStartTime;
  late final Timer _timer;
  Duration _elapsedTime = Duration.zero;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeRenderers();
    _setupPeerConnection();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), _updateElapsedTime);
    _startAudioLevelMonitoring();
  }

  Future<void> _initializeRenderers() async {
    print("Initializing renderers");
    await _localRTCVideoRenderer.initialize();
    await _remoteRTCVideoRenderer.initialize();
    print("Renderers initialized");
  }

  Future<void> _setupPeerConnection() async {
    try {
      print("Setting up peer connection");
      _rtcPeerConnection = await createPeerConnection({
        'iceServers': [
          {'urls': 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302'}
        ]
      });
      print("Peer connection created");

      await Helper.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
      print("Speakerphone set to on");

      _rtcPeerConnection!.onTrack = (event) {
        print("Received track: ${event.track.kind}");
        if (event.track.kind == 'audio') {
          print("Setting remote audio stream");
          _remoteRTCVideoRenderer.srcObject = event.streams[0];
          setState(() {
            isCallActive = true;
            callStartTime = DateTime.now();
          });
        }
      };

      _rtcPeerConnection!.onIceCandidate = (RTCIceCandidate candidate) {
        print("New ICE candidate: ${candidate.candidate}");
        rtcIceCandidates.add(candidate);
      };

      print("Getting local audio stream");
      _localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        'audio': {
          'echoCancellation': true,
          'noiseSuppression': true,
          'autoGainControl': true
        },
        'video': false
      });
      print("Local audio stream obtained");

      _localStream!.getTracks().forEach((track) {
        print("Adding local track: ${track.kind}");
        _rtcPeerConnection!.addTrack(track, _localStream!);
      });

      if (widget.offer != null) {
        socket!.on("IceCandidate", (data) {
          print("Received ICE candidate: ${data["iceCandidate"]["candidate"]}");
          String candidate = data["iceCandidate"]["candidate"];
          String sdpMid = data["iceCandidate"]["id"];
          int sdpMLineIndex = data["iceCandidate"]["label"];

          _rtcPeerConnection!.addCandidate(RTCIceCandidate(
            candidate,
            sdpMid,
            sdpMLineIndex,
          ));
        });

        print("Setting remote description from offer");
        await _rtcPeerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(
          RTCSessionDescription(widget.offer["sdp"], widget.offer["type"]),
        );

        print("Creating answer");
        RTCSessionDescription answer = await _rtcPeerConnection!.createAnswer();
        print("Created answer SDP: ${answer.sdp}");
        await _rtcPeerConnection!.setLocalDescription(answer);

        socket!.emit("answerCall", {
          "callerId": widget.callerId,
          "sdpAnswer": answer.toMap(),
        });
      } else {
        socket!.on("callAnswered", (data) async {
          print("Received answer SDP: ${data["sdpAnswer"]["sdp"]}");
          await _rtcPeerConnection!.setRemoteDescription(
            RTCSessionDescription(
              data["sdpAnswer"]["sdp"],
              data["sdpAnswer"]["type"],
            ),
          );

          for (RTCIceCandidate candidate in rtcIceCandidates) {
            print("Sending ICE candidate: ${candidate.candidate}");
            socket!.emit("IceCandidate", {
              "calleeId": widget.calleeId,
              "iceCandidate": {
                "id": candidate.sdpMid,
                "label": candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
                "candidate": candidate.candidate
              }
            });
          }

          setState(() {
            isCallActive = true;
            callStartTime = DateTime.now();
          });
        });

        print("Creating offer");
        RTCSessionDescription offer = await _rtcPeerConnection!.createOffer();
        print("Created offer SDP: ${offer.sdp}");
        await _rtcPeerConnection!.setLocalDescription(offer);

        socket!.emit('makeCall', {
          "calleeId": widget.calleeId,
          "sdpOffer": offer.toMap(),
        });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error setting up peer connection: $e');
    }
  }

  void _updateElapsedTime(Timer timer) {
    if (callStartTime != null) {
      setState(() {
        _elapsedTime = DateTime.now().difference(callStartTime!);
      });
    }
  }

  void _leaveCall() {
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  void _toggleMic() {
    setState(() {
      isAudioOn = !isAudioOn;
      _localStream?.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) {
        track.enabled = isAudioOn;
      });
    });
  }

  void _startAudioLevelMonitoring() {
    Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 500), (timer) async {
      if (_rtcPeerConnection != null) {
        try {
          List<StatsReport> stats = await _rtcPeerConnection!.getStats();
          stats.forEach((report) {
            if (report.type == 'inbound-rtp' &&
                report.values['mediaType'] == 'audio') {
              print("Inbound audio level: ${report.values['audioLevel']}");
            } else if (report.type == 'outbound-rtp' &&
                report.values['mediaType'] == 'audio') {
              print("Outbound audio level: ${report.values['audioLevel']}");
            }
          });
        } catch (e) {
          print("Error getting stats: $e");
          // If the peer connection is null, stop the timer
          if (e.toString().contains("peerConnection is null")) {
            timer.cancel();
            print("Audio level monitoring stopped due to null peer connection");
          }
        }
      } else {
        print("RTCPeerConnection is null, cannot get stats");
        timer.cancel();
        print("Audio level monitoring stopped due to null peer connection");
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    print("Disposing CallScreen");
    _localRTCVideoRenderer.dispose();
    _remoteRTCVideoRenderer.dispose();
    _localStream?.dispose();
    if (_rtcPeerConnection != null) {
      _rtcPeerConnection!.close();
      _rtcPeerConnection = null;
    }
    _timer.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String formattedTime =
        "${_elapsedTime.inMinutes}:${(_elapsedTime.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}";

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Audio Call"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              if (isCallActive)
                Text(
                  "Call Duration: $formattedTime",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )
              else
                Text("Audio Call in Progress"),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(isAudioOn ? Icons.mic : Icons.mic_off),
                      onPressed: _toggleMic,
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.call_end),
                      iconSize: 30,
                      onPressed: _leaveCall,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

So that's my call screen and before it the join screen.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'call_screen.dart';
import '../services/signalling.service.dart';

class JoinScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selfCallerId;
  const JoinScreen({super.key, required this.selfCallerId});
  @override
  State<JoinScreen> createState() => _JoinScreenState();
}

class _JoinScreenState extends State<JoinScreen> {
  dynamic incomingSDPOffer;
  final remoteCallerIdTextEditingController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // listen for incoming video call
    SignallingService.instance.socket!.on("newCall", (data) {
      if (mounted) {
        // set SDP Offer of incoming call
        setState(() => incomingSDPOffer = data);
      }
    });
  }

  // join Call
  _joinCall({
    required String callerId,
    required String calleeId,
    dynamic offer,
  }) {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) => CallScreen(
          callerId: callerId,
          calleeId: calleeId,
          offer: offer,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text("P2P Call App"),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      controller: TextEditingController(
                        text: widget.selfCallerId,
                      ),
                      readOnly: true,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      enableInteractiveSelection: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Your Caller ID",
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 12),
                    TextField(
                      controller: remoteCallerIdTextEditingController,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Remote Caller ID",
                        alignLabelWithHint: true,
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 24),
                    ElevatedButton(
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white30),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        "Invite",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        _joinCall(
                          callerId: widget.selfCallerId,
                          calleeId: '65ef7b6458ceb20f20336c43',
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (incomingSDPOffer != null)
              Positioned(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "Incoming Call from ${incomingSDPOffer["callerId"]}",
                  ),
                  trailing: Row(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.call_end),
                        color: Colors.redAccent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() => incomingSDPOffer = null);
                        },
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.call),
                        color: Colors.greenAccent,
                        onPressed: () {
                          _joinCall(
                            callerId: incomingSDPOffer["callerId"]!,
                            calleeId: widget.selfCallerId,
                            offer: incomingSDPOffer["sdpOffer"],
                          );
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


These are static idk I'm connecting to backend so I'm connecting with 2 emulators and I do connect because I made the timer start when the other user connecting but there are no audio.
So I followed the demo I'm connecting it with the sockets and everything but no audio are appearing not even the mic icon the become in the right top corner. Even when I tried video but become a black screen and I added the permissions in andriod.mainfist and infoplist is right and  signaling and I tried a real devices too.
